# Default mipmap level & elements to use for CopyTexture in Unity Scripting?

Tags: unity, mipmaps, rendertexture

I want to make a tiled map. I want to use the function [CopyTexture](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html) to copy from a Texture2D (where is stored my tileset) to a RenderTexture.

I want to use the third overloading (with all the arguments) which allow me to choose from where in the source texture and where in the render texture I will copy. But I need to specify mipmap levels and elements.

I don't know what to use as mipmap levels and elements in this function. Thanks to everyone who can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`0`

The parameter name suggests it is which mip to *read from* and you will almost certainly want to read from the largest (original) texture which is mip-0.

Comment: Ok thanks ! Do you have an idea on the srcElement & dstElement parameters too ?

Comment: Those are the `cubemap face, texture array layer or 3D texture depth slice` so you probably also want `0` (the "first" image in the collection of 1).